# Alternative to dynamic table selection in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've been told that it's bad practice to select a table in a MySQL query dynamically, and I cannot find an alternative method to my current code other than putting everything into one table. If that doesn't make sense maybe my current code will make more sense.

```
$where = $_GET['section'];
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT title, img, active, price FROM ? ORDER by ID limit 5 ")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $where);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        if ($row['active'] == "yes") {
            echo'
```

I now know that you cannot use a prepared statement to select a table, but I'm not sure how to tackle this now.

Would something like:

```
$where = $_GET['section'];
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if ($where == "sets") {
    $query = "SELECT title, img, active, price FROM sets;"
}

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        if ($row['active'] == "yes") {
            echo'do stuff here';
        }
```

But I'm sure that's also bad practice. Any pointers in which direction I should take this are appreciated, I apologize for the long post.

Comment: Is it that you have several tables with the same (or very similar) structure? Is there a good reason not to combine them all as one table?

Comment: @Okonomiyaki The tables are similar, except I'd like the get variable in the url to make it put out different products. I could put them all into one table, but there's alot of products.

Comment: Probably, you can put all of these products in one table, add a 'section' column, and put an index on that column. How many millions of products do you have, actually?

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically choose a table name *if* you verify its validity with a whitelist of acceptable values.  Since you cannot, as you've discovered, use a prepared statement placeholder for a table name, this is the most secure alternative.

```
// Build an array of table names you will permit in this query
$valid_tables = array('sets', 'othertable', 'othertable2');

// Verfiy that $_GET['section'] is one of your permitted table strings
// by using in_array()
if (in_array($_GET['section'], $valid_tables)) {
  // Build and execute your query
  $where = $_GET['section']
  $query = "SELECT title, img, active, price FROM $where;";
  // etc...
}
else {
  // Invalid table name submitted.  Don't query!!!
}
```

Comment: Alternatively to a hard-coded whitelist, run and capture a `SHOW TABLES` query first to get the live list of tables in the DB to use as the whitelist: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html.  Of course, you may still have to be programatically picky about which tables you're willing to allow the client to operate on.